Derivation of the "Chain syllogism" rule in first order logic
I'm currently reading these: https://www.mcmp.philosophie.uni-muenchen.de/students/math/math_logic_munich.pdf lecture notes and am kind of stuck on the proof on page 58 line 4 where $$\Gamma \lnot \varphi \lnot \varphi$$ is derived using (Ass.). I don't understand how, none of the rule thus far introduced allow me to manipulated the consequent except contradiction which I can't use in this case. Am I misunderstanding something? Is there maybe another way to prove it with the given tools?

wow this (the text ur using) has to be the worst choice of notation I've ever seen

It is the Assumption rule (page 53): we can derive $\Gamma \ \varphi$ [that is the sequent usually written: $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$] whenever $\varphi$ is a formula which is a member of $\Gamma$.
Assumption rule has no premise (no sequent on top of the rule): this means that we can introduce the sequent at a stage whatever of the proof.
In step 4. the antecedent of the sequent is $\Gamma \lnot \varphi$ and the consequent is $\lnot \varphi$ again.
Having derived in step 3. the sequent $\Gamma \lnot \varphi \ \varphi$, and having $\Gamma \lnot \varphi \ \lnot \varphi$ in step 4., we are able to use Triviality rule (aka: Ex Falso) to derive: $\Gamma \lnot \varphi \ \psi$.

I don't quite get how the assumption rule gives me $$\Gamma \lnot \varphi \lnot \varphi$$ though, as far as I understand it it lets me add a sequent member at the end of a sequent I already have, but $$\Gamma \lnot \varphi$$ hasn't been derived.

@Fabio - unfotunately, the author's choice of symbol is a little bit misleading; let use $\vdash$ to separate the antecedent from the consequent. The (Ass) rule says $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ is correct provided that $\varphi \in \Gamma$. Now, in step 4 we have $\Gamma' \vdash \lnot \varphi$ where $\Gamma'=\Gamma, \lnot \varphi$. Thus, the condition for (Ass) is satisfied.

@Fabio - we do not derive the antecedent: we derive sequents. Assumption rule has no premise (no sequent on top of the rule): this means that we can introduce the sequent at a stage whatever of the proof.
